# Excluding a string in Regex

Tags: regex, string, search

I have a long text and a I need to isolate single word between two other words.

This is a part of the text I have:

```
2012-05-05 19:31:44 status config-files gwibber-service 3.4.0-0ubuntu4
2012-05-05 19:31:44 status not-installed gwibber-service <none>
2012-05-05 19:31:45 status installed gir1.2-notify-0.7 0.7.5-1
2012-05-05 19:31:45 remove gir1.2-notify-0.7 0.7.5-1 <none>
2012-05-05 19:31:45 status half-configured gir1.2-notify-0.7 0.7.5-1
2012-05-05 19:31:45 status half-installed gir1.2-notify-0.7 0.7.5-1
```

Now I want to select all the words and number excpet that, for example:

```
gir1.2-notify-0.7
```

so I replace them with " " (pratically delete all other words and numbers)..
what I thought, there are two keywords that I can use to isolate them: "remove" and "{some numbers and .} <none>"
everything between them must be excluded...

I hope you got it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
(?<=remove)\s+([\w\.\-]+)\b
```

*This is nothing but a simple `positive look-behind` approach. For better understanding visit [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*

Answer (score 0):

```
r"\w[\w-]*[\.]{1}\w[\w-\.]*"  /// -> it will match all strings of the form ->
```

[one-alphanumeric-character][(zero-or-more-alphanumeric-chararcters-or-"-")].[one-alphanumeric-character][(zero-or-more-alphanumeric-chararcters-or-"-")]

so it will match girl1.2-notify-0.7 but it will not match gwibber-service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I really understand your question, but...

using the following regex: `remove(.*)<none>$`
`$1` would give you " gir1.2-notify-0.7 "

I don't think you'll be able to select/replace everything EXCEPT $1 in a single statement, you'll probably have to roll some code to process based on the results of what the regex returns.